# CollapsingToolbar and SideMenu

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

My app have an issue with CollapsingToolbar and a side menu that i created..
I Have a AppBarLayout with a CollapsingToolbar, it works perfectly.
And in a point, i create another view in front of all..
And this view have another ScrollView, but this scrollview only works above the CollapsingToolbar, seens like the collapsing is still in front of my view..
and when i try to scroll where the collapsing are, the scroll dont work for my new view, and work for the collapsing, trying to hide.

[AppImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uordm.png)

my Collapsing toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:titleEnabled="false"

        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            >
                ....
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

the new view, is just a relative layout with some components

Theres a way to "lock" this CollapsingToolbar, make the new view enter with priority, because seens like that the CollapsingToolbar is always on top of everythin!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please glad us by adding some code about what you have done?